# Is battery consumption linear?

Tags: battery, battery-life, battery-history

I am benchmarking an app using the batteryhistorian. 
The result is a chart where every percentile is a "tick".

After I've measured the battery consumption
and let the battery drain to half, I would like to be able to save time
by making  a change and restarting a measurment without having charged 
the deviced back to full.

**Is it a fair approximation to assume that a drop from 85% to 84% is the same
as a drop from say 64% to 63% when benchmarking an application?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Li Ion [battery discharge](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharge_methods) is not strictly linear, (unlike a capacitor ). This ensures available power is utilised till the end of battery charge

[image]

- But it is [fairly linear, more so at lower loads](http://www.richtek.com/battery-management/en) as can be seen from this figure, where [C-rate or charge rate](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_is_the_c_rate) is the discharge/ charge rate

[image]

- Assuming your app is not a heavy power hog, it is reasonable to extraploate discharge. But, since the discharge isn't strictly linear, it would give better results if

  - Battery drop interval is more , say 5 to 10% and not 1% as proposed
  - Battery drop is not measured below 30% of battery ( to avoid greying into non linear portion of curve)
  - Measuring at 1% drop inherently introduces rounding off errors- if your phone has two digit accuracy, anything between 75.90 to 75.99 would show 76% . In the worst case, the error could be doubled (it won't fall to 75% till it goes below 75.90). Which means a 20% error, and that can be reduced to 2% over a 10% drop
  - Avoid measuring when the [battery is fully charged](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=871051) to reduce errors. Measure at about 85% for the first reading and around 50% (or higher ) for second reading after tweaking your app